# Respostas "em desenvolvimento"

Tags: debate, comportamento, respostas

Não raro eu vejo várias respostas com trechos indicando que a mesma está "em desenvolvimento" ou "em andamento", conforme o exemplo da imagem abaixo:

[image: Resposta "em desenvolvimento"]

Já vi inclusive casos em que o autor da resposta simplesmente "marcou" a mesma como "concluo depois".

Geralmente esse comportamento pode ser observado em respostas grandes, onde o autor vai complementado através de várias edições.

**Minha pergunta é:** essa prática é razoável neste site?

Me parece que tal prática não ajuda em nada, afinal, se a resposta não está pronta não deveria ser postada. Tenho a impressão que os autores dessas respostas fazem isso na ânsia de ser o primeiro a responder.

Comment: Eu faço isso com medo do meu nagevador travar ou dar timeout e perder o que eu havia feito. Não vejo como uma má prática, considerando o produto final. Qualidade é o que nos interessa. Agora, aceitar a resposta antes dela ser concluída eu também não entendo. Aconteceu comigo, inclusive nessa pergunta, e particularmente não vejo sentido, mas isso é o AP que decide se já abordou o problema ou não.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss se não me engano, o próprio SO salva um rascunho da resposta automaticamente de tempos em tempos. Assim, se você sair da página antes de postar e resposta e retornar, seu rascunho estará lá. Ou você pode usar um editor de texto externo para formular sua resposta, apesar de que você não teria o preview do markdown. Usuários aceitarem uma resposta antes de ela estar "pronta" me parece mais um argumento contra essa prática.

Comment: Você também pode adicionar uma resposta, remover, editar a resposta removida e em seguida restaurá-la. Isso preserva a resposta no site.

Comment: E como isso ficaria melhor do que a resposta ali visível? Pois mesmo as edições em uma resposta excluída fariam a pergunta subir para a página inicial novamente. Não é mais fácil deixar visível para que as pessoas possam acompanhando o conteúdo e já corrigir possíveis erros durante o processo?

Comment: Acho que o ideal seria postar a resposta apenas quando ela estiver razoavelmente "pronta". Se você está postando uma resposta e sabe de antemão que fará uma edição em seguida, então, eu considero que ela não está pronta.

Comment: [As vezes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96464/91)  o pessoal acaba esquecendo :)

Comment: @rray kkkkkkkkk bota "esquecendo" nisso :p

Comment: 2015... Já é Alzheimer... hehehe

Answer (score 11):

**Resumo:** a discussão aqui sobre isso é muito válida e eu particularmente nunca havia me questionado sobre isso, mas acho que essa prática, se bem usada como, ao meu ver, é hoje, só traz benefícios e nenhum malefício.

> Essa prática é razoável neste site?

Não é algo muito comum, mas alguns usuários a fazem. Eu, inclusive, tal como na resposta citada. Particularmente não vejo como tal prática pode prejudicar, de qualquer forma, a comunidade. Já, em contrapartida, partindo da premissa que a resposta será completada, vejo que a comunidade ganha muito com o resultado final: uma resposta que busca ser completa e de qualidade. Não afirmo que as minhas são assim necessariamente, mas posso afirmar que é sempre essa a minha intenção. Sobre o tamanho da resposta, não vejo relevância, pode ser pequena ou grande, o que eu avalio é qualidade e completude. Resumindo, se utilizada com moderação (ler resto da resposta), não vejo mal algum.

> Me parece que tal prática não ajuda em nada, afinal, se a resposta não está pronta não deveria ser postada.

Isso é verdade em partes, ao meu ver. Primeiro, acho que não é a prática que deve ser avaliada, mas sim a resposta e isso completa a segunda parte da sua afirmação. Se a primeira versão da resposta, mesmo incompleta, já possui conteúdo que pode ser absorvido pela comunidade dentro do contexto da pergunta, tal prática só traz benefícios e nenhum malefício. Isto é, a resposta deve ser apenas postada se ela, da maneira que está, pudesse ser considerada como uma resposta completa (ou praticamente completa). Tanto que geralmente tais respostas, se não fosse postadas com o aviso "Em desenvolvimento", esta discussão nem iria existir. A questão é: colocar esse aviso traz mesmo algum prejuízo à comunidade? Se eu posto sem o aviso, mesmo sabendo que iria completar a resposta depois, ninguém iria se importar, então não é a prática que deve ser discutida.

Obviamente que isso ocorre se bem aplicada, como qualquer outra coisa. Publicar respostas como "*Sim, funciona, mas completo a resposta depois*" seria, ao meu ver, abusar desta prática, pois inicialmente não traz benefício algum para a comunidade; não há conteúdo que possa ser absorvido desde o início. Considerando que todas as respostas que fiz assim (espero eu) apresentam já no início algum conteúdo e que mesmo outros usuários a fazem, não vejo como má prática. Eu até incentivaria que os usuários a fizessem, pois hora ou outra iria sair respostas espetaculares.

> Tenho a impressão que os autores dessas respostas fazem isso na ânsia de ser o primeiro a responder.

Não posso responder por todos os usuários que utilizam essa prática, mas eu mesmo não importo muito com isso. Se eu tenho um conteúdo que pode ser interessante à comunidade, irei postar independente de ser o primeiro ou não. Existir uma resposta, seja ela boa ou não, aceitada ou não, não deve ser agente bloqueador para outras respostas. Um exemplo bom é a pergunta:

[Para que serve o with no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878)

A pergunta é de 2015, já possuía uma resposta do bigown com 14 votos e aceita, mas uma discussão no chat gerou outras duas respostas bem votadas. A questão é: a ordem de quem responde, seja o primeiro ou não, não faz diferença, então acho que essa seria uma impressão errada que você criou.

> Porém geralmente quando um usuário usa desse artifício de marcar a resposta como "em construção" as edições são sequenciais.

Se as edições são para melhorar a resposta, só temos a ganhar com isso.

> Um outro detalhe é que as pessoas não são notificadas quando sua resposta está "pronta".

De fato, não, mas não vejo isso como um agravante a ponto de condenar a prática. As respostas devem (ou deveriam) ser elaboradas não só pensando em responder diretamente ao autor da pergunta, mas sim atender o máximo de usuários possível. Entre um usuário ter que ficar verificando a própria pergunta e ter um grande número de usuários agraciados com a resposta, eu prefiro a segunda opção (quando eu tenho condições de criar uma resposta para tal).

> Acerca da resposta ser aceita antes de concluída.

Bom, isso só depende no autor da pergunta. Se a resposta parcial já atende todos os questionamentos da pergunta, sem problemas em aceitá-la. Agora, se o autor aceitou uma resposta claramente incompleta, será interessante orientá-lo melhor de como funciona o site, pois talvez seja desconhecimento por parte dele.

Comment: Concordo com a parte sobre ser o primeiro ou não. Já aconteceu um caso em que o AP tinha aceitado uma resposta, então fui e respondi também, ele achou que minha resposta atendia melhor, e colocou como correta. Então não acho que faça diferença a ordem, desde que a resposta seja boa. Ainda que o AP não aceite como melhor resposta, ela pode ser útil para alguém no futuro. Eu costumo ler sempre todas as respostas, porque nem sempre a aceita é a melhor.

Answer (score 9):

Isso era um comentário, mas ficou muito grande.

Eu faço isso quando preciso sair e acho que a resposta já tem conteúdo relevante.

Particularmente, não vejo muito problema na "prática" citada. A ânsia de ser o primeiro a responder pode ser real, mas até que ponto ela é realmente prejudicial?

Falando especificamente da [resposta supracitada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/228023/18246), a primeira versão dela já atendia a pergunta, inclusive, muito bem. Ele foi complementando e tá construindo uma resposta realmente incrível e bem detalhada.

Outra coisa que deve ser notada é que uma resposta daquele porte não é escrita "numa pegada" só. É preciso ler, reler, mexer aqui, mexer ali, descansar um pouco, pensar em outras coisas e ir editando conforme conseguir.

É, também, importante lembrar que nenhum de nós aqui é pago pra contribuir com o site. Ou seja, todos nós temos tarefas fora daqui e muitas destas com importância/urgência maior do que "terminar de escrever a minha resposta". Tendo isso em vista, eu questiono:

Se a resposta já tem um conteúdo relevante, mesmo que breve e/ou introdutório é mesmo justo com o autor da resposta pedir para que ele só poste depois que tiver terminado a mesma?

Comment: No meu caso nunca foi a ânsia por ser o primeiro. Nem faz diferença. Faço isso mais pelo "aproveitem aí o que eu já escrevi" :D

Comment: Talvez esse seja o ponto: se a resposta já tem conteúdo relevante, como você citou, acredito que você possa postá-la, porém sem a necessidade de indicar que ela está "em construção", afinal, ela está pronta (com conteúdo suficiente para responder a questão). Quando você diz que uma resposta grande e com qualidade não é escrita em uma pegada só, eu concordo. Porém geralmente quando um usuário usa desse artifício de marcar a resposta como "em construção" as edições são sequenciais, logo após a primeira versão da resposta.

Comment: @BrunoPeres Acho que quem pode definir se existe a necessidade de sinalizar isso ou não é o autor. Eu levo isso com um aviso, do tipo: "vou mexer aqui, fica de olho ou olha mais tarde". E sobre as edições serem sequenciais: qual o problema nisso? Eu mesmo gosto de ficar uns 2 e minutos parado pra depois ler e voltar a escrever.

Comment: _Acho que quem pode definir se existe a necessidade de sinalizar isso ou não é o autor._  Concordo. Agora, ser um comportamento adequado ou não é outra história. Também não vejo problema com as edições. Porém eu espero que elas sejam usadas para melhorar uma resposta, e não para completar uma resposta incompleta que já se sabia de antemão que seria editada, apenas com o propósito de postar primeiro ou algo do tipo. Não estou dizendo nem acredito que seja o seu caso ou da resposta usada como exemplo nesta questão.

Comment: Um outro detalhe é que as pessoas não são notificadas quando sua resposta está "pronta". Parece-me que este artifício utiliza de um recurso disponibilizado pelo site para uma finalidade para a qual ele não foi feito.

Comment: A questão é que quase nunca é este o caso. Óbvio que existe, e nós geralmente sabemos quando existe essa intenção. É chato, mas não é não tão problemático quanto você está tentando fazer parecer. Na verdade, a ânsia de ser o primeiro respondedor (se é que ela existe) só mostra que o problema não é como agimos perante a prática, mas sim que algo tende a incentivar o usuário a ser o primeiro a postar uma resposta, seja por falta de entendimento do site, porque parece que quem posta primeiro ganha mais votos ou qualquer coisa que seja. Neste caso específico o melhor a fazer é instruir o AR.

Comment: @BrunoPeres E nem vão ser notificadas. É uma forma que encontramos para suprir a falta de uma ferramenta adequada pra isso.

Comment: Na verdade não estou tentando fazer parecer mais problemático do que é. Inclusive não acho que seja um problema enorme, assim como vários outros não o são. Porém, nem por isso deixa de valer a pena discuti-los.

Comment: Na verdade, foi falha essa expressão usada por mim.

Comment: Entendo que deixar claro que a resposta está em desenvolvimento não é prejudicial, pelo contrário, é uma forma de avisar ao AP que você ainda pretende complementar a resposta. Isso serve como dica para o AP ainda não aceitar a resposta, e aguardar até que ela seja concluída. Caso o autor da resposta não desse essa dica, poderia ocorrer do AP aceitar a resposta antes da hora (sei que isso ocorre com ou sem a dica, mas precisaríamos avaliar se é maioria ou minoria).

Comment: Sobre notificação, uma forma seria o autor da resposta adicionar um comentário na pergunta *"editei minha resposta"* (claro que isso fica ruim se ele resolver editar a resposta várias vezes), ou mesmo excluir a pergunta e a postar novamente (claro que ele não faria isso se já tivesse votos positivos). Não sei se isso é bom, é só uma dica que pensei rapidamente, sem avaliar os lados negativos (ex: comentários não deveriam ser usados para esse propósito, mas isso é prejudicial?).